# Do I need to make a method in an object to call it's own properties?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how to work with objects in javascript. The MonsterSpawn property for the Monster object is always 0 and I assume that's because it can't find the name array until an object is initialized? Should I instead make a method inside this object which sets the MonsterSpawn property? Is there a better way to do this? The code worked fine without using objects so it's something I'm missunderstanding.

```js
const Monster = {
    name:[ "Ogre", "Troll", "Rat", "Goblin"],
    MonsterSpawn: Math.floor(Math.random() * name.length),
    MonsterHp: Math.floor(Math.random() * 99),
    spawnMonster:{
    }
}
```

Comment: _"The MonsterSpawn property for the Monster object is always 0"_ - no, it is not, as a simple `console.log(Monster);` directly after the code you have shown, proves. If you were actually talking about trying to _access_ it, for example from within that `spawnMonster` method - that would only work if you knew the object name `Monster` at this point already. Depending on what you are actually trying to achieve here, you should perhaps rather implement a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the properties inside your object, you could use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). The getter will be able to access the properties inside its own object using `this`. So, if we take your code and implement a getter using the `get` keyword, it would be something like this:

```js
const Monster = {
    name:[ "Ogre", "Troll", "Rat", "Goblin"],
    get MonsterSpawn() { return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.name.length) },
    MonsterHp: Math.floor(Math.random() * 99),
    spawnMonster:{
    }
}

console.log(Monster);
```

Note that the `MonsterSpawn` property looks like it's a function and you would think you have invoke it as if it's a function, but it's actually a property. So, accessing it, you wouldn't invoke it like `Monster.MonsterSpawn();` but call its property like `Monster.MonsterSpawn;` instead.